# Power Query Parameter works in one table but not another

Tags: powerquery

So I have two tables (power query), and want to combine them into one. The second table just looks at the first table (power query) and applies a parameter filter to it. When i try to combine the parameter code into the original query the filter doesn't work. I have enabled fast combine to made all queries public to get rid of any firewall issues.

So as not to break the original working set of pq, i duplicated the first pq and modified using advanced by coping the needed code to apply the parameter (third pq)

**Second power query code (this looks at first pq an applies a parameter filter) and it works**

```
let
    Date_Parameter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameter"]}[Content],
    Date_Value = Date_Parameter{0}[Value],
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Timesheet1"]}[Content],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Date] = Date_Value))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

**Third power query code (this is the one where i duplicated the first pq and added parameter code from second pq) this doesn't work**

```
let

    Date_Parameter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameter"]}[Content],
    Date_Value = Date_Parameter{0}[Value],

    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("\\192.168.12.31\Project Files\Daily Truck Sheet\TimeTrack\TimeTrack.xlsm")),
    Timesheet_Table = Source{[Item="Timesheet",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    Merge = Table.NestedJoin(Timesheet_Table,{"Ref"},Project,{"Ref"},"NewColumn"),
    #"Expand NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Merge, "NewColumn", {"Crew"}, {"NewColumn.Crew"}),
    #"Renamed Columns"  = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expand NewColumn",{{"NewColumn.Crew", "Crew"}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Renamed Columns", {"Ref"}),
    #"Removed Columns"  = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{"Ref", "Employee Name", "Truck #", "Hours", "Per Diem", "Piecework", "Travel Day", "Timecard Filename", "Paid DT Hrs.", "hours check", "project hours", "Paid Regular Hours", "Paid  OT  Hrs.", "PayPeriod", "Employee Number", "Lead Hand Employee Number", "Crew Count", "Employee Revenue"}),
    #"Reordered Columns"= Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Date", "Date Received", "Lead Hand", "Crew", "Project#", "Comments", "Work Performed", "time card hours", "Revenue per hour", "Total Reveneu"}),
    Rounding = Table.TransformColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Revenue per hour", each Number.Round(_, 2)}, {"Total Reveneu", each Number.Round(_, 2)}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Rounding, each ([Date] = Date_Value))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i had to insert a transform for pq to treat as a date. Even though in the Parameter pq (that loads the value from the parameter table) it is already transformed. replaced the first three lines before the source line with the following and it worked

```
Date_Parameter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameter"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Date_Parameter,{{"Value", type date}}),
Date_Value = #"Changed Type1"{0}[Value],
```

So maybe now i can get rid of the parameter pq as it is all built into the final pq but haven't tried yet

Comment: Because a date in Excel is largely just a number with special formatting, we often can't recover the information that it should be a date.